# For what values of $k$ is $p(x) = k(1-r^2)^x$ a valid probability mass function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The question is asking for values for $k$ making this a valid probability mass function.

where $$P(x) =  k(1-r^2)^x$$

for $x = 0,1,2...$ and $P(x)= 0$ otherwise

$r$ is elected from interval $(0,1)$

I'm thinking this is a discrete probability distribution that needs to sum to 1, but the text is very light on and I'm at a bit of a loss how to solve this.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Summing over $x$, $$1=\sum_{x=0}^\infty P(x) = k\sum_{x=0}^\infty (1-r^2)^x = \frac{k}{1-(1-r^2)}$$
by the geometric series formula. So $k=r^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you recognize it as a [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) pmf

$$P(X=x) = p(1-p)^x, \: x=0,1,2,...$$

with $p=r^2$ then it's immediately obvious that $k=p$.

Of course if you don't recognize the pmf then it's at least useful to recognize that it's a geometric series.